# Insert data in current table and update another table MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problem with inserting in purchase table and updating facility table. Let's say, user made a purchase with product_id and product_quantity.

The query is running. But it inserts twice with the same data and not updating facility table.

When user hit submit, I want to insert product_id and product_quantity into purchase table. And updating facility table with product_id and product_quantity that associated with it.

Here is my code

```
<?php
include 'dbconn.inc.php';
include 'functions.inc.php';

 $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM facilities";

 $res = $mysqli->query($sql1);
 $facilities = array();

 while( $row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ){

 $facilities[]['id'] = $facilities_id;
 $facilities[]['product_id'] = $facilities_product_id;
 $facilities[]['product_current_quantity'] = $product_current_quantity;
}


 $id = $mysqli->real_escape_string ($_POST['id']);
 $purchase_id = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['purchase_id'] );
 $facility_id = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['facility_id'] );
 $product_quantity = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['product_quantity'] );



 $sql1 = "UPDATE facilities
 SET

 `product_current_quantity` = '$product_quantity + $product_current_quantity'


 WHERE $facility_id = $facilities_id AND $id = $facilities_product_id ";


 $sql = "INSERT INTO purchases
 (
 `purchase_id`,
 `facility_id`, 
 `product_quantity`,,
  `product_id`
  )
  VALUES
  (

  '$purchase_id',
  '$facility_id',
  '$product_quantity',
  '$id'

   )";
```

I did some research and I think I need to use triggers. But I never work with triggers before. Any helps would be great. Thank you!

Comment: "*At the same time*" means nothing in databases. There's always an order. What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: SQL seems fine, but you're not running it in the code. If you are running, and the database is not updating/updating properly, please say so.

Comment: The query is running but it inserts data twice in the purchase table and not updating the facilities table at all.

Comment: @DavidChen I explained above. Is there any ways to combine both query togther?

Answer (score 0):

Please execute your query and better use echo statement if you have doubt in query.
**use "php.net"**

Comment: please execute query like $mysqli->query($sql1); your code had not execute query code after insert and update query .

Comment: I found out that there is no value fetch from facilities table. How can I fetch data from another table?                            while( $row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ){

 $facilities[]['id'] = $facilities_id;
 $facilities[]['product_id'] = $facilities_product_id;
 $facilities[]['product_current_quantity'] = $product_current_quantity;
}

Comment: you can find like ...$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID LIMIT 3";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

/* associative array */
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 $name = $row["Name"];   ................please use php.net for more help thank you

Answer (score 0):

used this code to your updates

```
product_current_quantity = product_current_quantity + $product_current_quantity
```

how many number they can add to your product Quantity and they sum the current number.

Answer (score 0):

You have used insert query and update query for the same variable $sql without any condition. If so always your following query only executes. 
Then anymore no update only insertion will reflect in your table.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO purchases
 (
 `purchase_id`,
 `facility_id`, 
 `product_quantity`,,
  `product_id`
  )
  VALUES
  (

  '$purchase_id',
  '$facility_id',
  '$product_quantity',
  '$id'

   )";
```